# Is there an option to separate 2 column data from grouping data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this data in my temporary table:

```
cid | storenum |  busidate   | gcode | total |
10  |   010    | 2019-04-05  |  868  | 55456 |
127 |   010    | 2019-04-05  |  868  | 61000 |
```

I want to grouping by query some data to get an output like this

```
storenum | busidate   | gcode |          total 1          | total 2
   010   | 2019-04-05 |  868  | 55456 (from row cid 10)   | 61000 (from row cid 127)
```

I have queried like

```
SELECT storenum, busidate, gcode
FROM #temporarytable
GROUP BY storenum, busidate, gcode
```

how to put the grouping data into another column separated?

Comment: What is the logic behind the two total columns?  This is not clear from your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the 2 records has the same storenum, busidate, gcode but have the different total... I want to grouping the row but put the total into new column, when the 'total' column from the first row must be put into 'total 1' and other 'total' column must be put into 'total 2' column..

Comment: The answers given below are already doing that, if you bother to actually try the code.  By the way, there is no "first" or "second" row in SQL, unless you specify one or more columns which determines that order.  So...which column(s) makes the first record "first?"

Comment: oh yah... i forgot somethin... the two rows has an id... but i forgot put into the question above

Answer (score 0):

We can try using `ROW_NUMBER` to help here.  For example, for three total columns we can try:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY storenum, busidate, gcode
                           ORDER BY cid) rn
    FROM #temporarytable
)

SELECT
    storenum,
    busidate,
    gcode,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN total END) AS total1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN total END) AS total2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN total END) AS total3
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    storenum,
    busidate,
    gcode;
```

This assumes that there exists a column `cid` which determines the order of the total values.

**Edit:**

If you are using a really old version of SQL Server (e.g. 2000) which does not have `ROW_NUMBER`, we might be able to simulate it:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t1.*,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #temporarytable t2 WHERE t2.cid <= t1.cid) rn
    FROM #temporarytable t1
)

SELECT
    storenum,
    busidate,
    gcode,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN total END) AS total1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN total END) AS total2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN total END) AS total3
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    storenum,
    busidate,
    gcode;
```

Comment: i just want the specific data and put into new column, so i mean the total 1 is from 1st row then total 2 from the other.. not to put random into total 1 and total 2

Comment: What makes one row the "first" row and the other the "second" row.  This is not clear.

Comment: imagine if the grouping data coming from 2 row and then the first 'total' row must be input into 'total 1' and the other 'total' row must be input into 'total 1'...

Comment: @JoeWilson I have updated my answer per your latest information.

Comment: My answer should work for any number of records per group, with the caveat that the number of columns would be fixed for the entire table.

Comment: This error occored... "'ROW_NUMBER' is not a recognized function name." I used SQL Server 2000

Comment: I don't know how to handle this problem in SQL Server 2000.  Please consider upgrading, as your database is almost _twenty_ years old.  `ROW_NUMBER` has been in SQL Server for at least 10-15 years now.

Comment: is there any alternative for that case?

Comment: Try my updated answer, which uses a correlated subquery to find a row number.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below

```
select storenum, busidate, gcode,max(case when rn=1 then total end) as total1,
max(case when rn=2 then total end) as total2
from
(
SELECT storenum, busidate, gcode,total,
row_number() over(partition by storenum, busidate, gcode order by total) as rn
FROM #temporarytable
)A group by storenum, busidate, gcode
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use PIVOT as below

```
    create table #store(
    cid int ,
    storenum nvarchar(10),
    busidate datetime,
    gcode int,
    total int
    )

   insert into #store
   values
   (10 , '010', '2019-04-05', 868, 55456),
   (11 , '010', '2019-04-05', 868, 61000),
   (12 , '010', '2019-04-05', 868, 7000)


   DECLARE @pivotCols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @colsNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

   SELECT @pivotCols= ISNULL(@pivotCols + ',','') + QUOTENAME(Total)
   FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(total, 0 ) AS Total FROM #store) AS cols


   SELECT @colsNames = ISNULL(@colsNames + ',','') + 'MAX(' + QUOTENAME(Total) + ') AS ' 
   + QUOTENAME('Total ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), RowNo))  
   FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(total, 0 ) AS Total,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Total 
   ASC) AS RowNo FROM #store) AS colsNoSpaces

   set @query = 'select  storenum,  busidate,   gcode, ' + @colsNames + '
   from #store
   pivot    
   (
     max(total)
     for total in ('+ @pivotCols + ')
   ) as p group by storenum,    busidate,   gcode'

   execute (@query)
```